# Message Passing in C++ Functions

Tags: c++, function, message

I'm trying to use one function (let's call it "loop") that, among other things, is responsible for incrementing a variable that represents the number of iterations my program has executed since startup (it is an FDTD simulation). I need to use this iterator variable for decision making in another function in my program, for example to carry out some action if a certain number of iterations have completed.

I know how to pass a variable by reference from main into a function, but I don't see how it is possible to then check the value of this variable using another function also called from main.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. If I pass the variable by reference into both functions, will both have the most recent copy of the variable at all times?
2. If I use a global variable defined outside of main (I know this is bad practice), can a function modify the value of that variable?  If it requires passing by reference into a function, how can this be done?
3. Is there some other way to maintain a synchronized, correct variable value available to two or more functions that doesn't involve one of the above methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I pass the variable by reference into both functions, will both have the most recent copy of the variable at all times?

They will refer the same variable, therefore, yes. When one modifies the variable, the other will be able to read the new "synchronized" value.

> If I use a global variable defined outside of main (I know this is bad practice), can a function modify the value of that variable?

Yes, but don't use global variables.

> If it requires passing by reference into a function, how can this be done?

It is as easy as receiving the input to the function as a reference:

```
void func(int&); // example
//           ^
```

> Is there some other way to maintain a synchronized, correct variable value available to two or more functions that doesn't involve one of the above methods?

It's probably a better idea to have a class instead, so that you can also protected your synchronized variable from external edits:

```
class your_class {
private:
    T synchronized;
public:
    void func_one();
    void func_two();
};
```

but it really depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the usefulness of using private vs. public variables in classes?  I'm not exactly a beginner at programming, but I have been trained so far to use a functional programming style for scientific applications, so this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Comment: @Scott, The `public` part of a class is its *interface* (what you want to call and use from the outside of the class); the `private` part is its *implementation*, which is, what the user of the class, doesn't need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

> > I know how to pass a variable by reference from main into a function, but I don't see how it is possible to then check the value of this variable using another function also called from main.

Yes, you can access the same variable in two different functions. As your two functions are called by main() in sequence. If your work is for simulation, may not need global in your case.

```
main()
{
int cnt;
loop(int &cnt)
action(int &cnt)
}
```

You can achieve the same via global variable.